# Using Rx semantics how would this flow materialize?

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android

When some List equals X amount of values (len)
change the state of xyz view.

Using RxBindings and RxJava fluidness, how would I approach this problem?

Comment: How have you approached the problem on your own?

Comment: @tMJ im far from uninitiated... but if you understand my problem why not just come forth with the knowledge. give me some direction to research upon. this requirement is super simple to those knowledgeable in rx. y is knowledge secret??

Comment: It is not a knowledge secret per se. Here at stackoverflow we assume that you have done your home work and then come up with the problem. Tagging a question to draw maximum attention, without actually lifting a finger is frowned upon. However, If you want a quick intro you may start from [here](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754)

Comment: so you instead of just flat out answering the question if you have an answer you send me to a intro to rx to read for xxx hours and then find an answer. nahhhhhh thats wack. and this is to help me? or to enforce your way of teaching ppl. i humbly disagree

Comment: You know what's really whack. People expecting someone else to do their job for them.

Comment: nah that sorta kinda thinking actually creates most technology movements. copying and enhancing. but hey its just two diff ways of going through this life. have a blessed day!

Answer (score 0):

Using RxJava, to update the state of a view using a stream that is partitioned into lists of x values:

```
stream.buffer(x).doOnNext(list -> updateView(list));
```

Comment: I think OP meant something entirely different. Probably he wants to observe a java list and update a view when the length of the list is some predefined number.

Comment: buffer was a hint in the right direction along with *https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables*...the from and defer operators. thanks...ill end up answering this one myself.